# My images wont show in html

Tags: html, image

```
<div class="image"
     style="background-image: url( '_assets/_img/home.jpg' );"
     data-insurance-key="home">
</div>
```

I also checked many times that the image was in the correct folder, and the file name is correct, knowing that html is case sensitive. Is there any other reason why it wouldn't show up on my webpage?

Comment: What is your directory structure? Maybe your html is in another working folder nested in another structure

Comment: What size is your `<div>`? If it’s 0px×0px, the picture won’t show. Have you looked into the debugger tools and observed which URL is being loaded?

Comment: Might you be missing the '/' before the url? If your htm is in a subfolder it wont refer to /_assets but to subfolder/_assets now

Comment: @Xufox are in the correct way I think...

Comment: Further to Xufox's comment: Open the browser's developer tools. Look in the Net tab to see what URL is requested for the image and what the response is. Look in the Elements tab and the Computed subtab to see what dimensions the element has.

Comment: @marcosperezgude do you mean directory structure as in windows, OS, etc. if so I'm using OS. my html is saved in only one place :/

Comment: I say relative paths, so there's no matter what operating system do you use. If your html is in `project/html` folder and your images in `project/images` folder, your code should be like this: `background-image:url(../images/image.png);`

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry but I have no clue what you mean. As I am a beginner to html

Comment: @CaraBrown — Most of my previous comment was in plain English (or at least basic user interface terms). What, precisely, do you not understand? Consider using Google to learn about terms you don't recognise.

Comment: @Quentin it was about looking into the Net tab and see what URL is... I'm not sure what the Net tab is and also have no idea what the elements tab and the computed subtab is

Comment: The Net tab is the tab with the word Net (or Network) on it. The elements tab is the tab with the word Elements on it. The Computed subtab is the tab, that is not on the main developer tools tab bar, with the word Computed on it.

Comment: @Quentin it said there was no response available on the net tab. The dimensions seem fine.

Comment: Don't worry anymore, figured out the problem, data insurance key was house not home. thanks for your help any way.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an empty `div`. The size of the `div` will be 0 by 0, which causes nothing to be displayed.

You can use this as proof:

```html
    <div class="image"
         style="background-image: url( 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc768be1b3c' );"
         data-insurance-key="home">
             &nbsp;<br />
             &nbsp;<br />
             &nbsp;<br />
    </div>
```

As soon as you put in some content, it works. You might just need to set the size by hand, or put in a `img` instead of a background if the background is the only content:

```
<div class="image"
     data-insurance-key="home">
         <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc768be1b3c" />
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is it had worked perfectly before until I added another picture in a completely different place of the html page.

Comment: Then it must be the path. Can you access the URL of the image from the browser? That would help analyse your flaw in the URL path.

Comment: Yeah the URL seems to be perfectly fine :/

Comment: it helps but it can't do the design I wanted for the webpage, however worse comes to worse I might use it

Comment: sorry I tried including your idea, and it seems to not work with this anymore either.

Comment: Don't worry anymore, figured out the problem, data insurance key was house not home. thanks for your help any way.